# How do I send an email each time a cell in a range is changed to specific data, and include corresponding heading information?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've got basic automatic emailing working great for when a single cell contains specific data, but I'm having issues figuring out how to do the following:

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DmeOuU-nb0yhxydidg-SOmwOz1SAqProncaLwDHLF5Q/edit?usp=sharing) in which I am trying to set up a time-driven script that searches range B2:D7 on Sheet1 for any cells that changed to 'HELP RQD' since the last time the script ran. For each match, an email needs to be sent with the corresponding column and row headers of that cell. The column headers have various random station names, and the row headers have various time values. The linked example looks like this:

[image: Example Sheet]

Example 1 - If Cell C7 receives the words 'HELP RQD' since the last script run: An email is sent which reads 'Help requested for **STATION 2** at **12:00**', and no more emails are sent about Cell C7 until its data is changed to something else and then is changed back to 'HELP RQD' once again.

Example 2 - If Cell C7 and Cell D3 receive the words 'HELP RQD' since the last script run: Two emails are sent, the first of which reads 'Help requested for **STATION 2** at **12:00**', and the second of which reads 'Help requested for **MACHINE III** at **8:00**', and no more emails are sent about Cell C7 or D3 until their data is changed to something else and then is changed back to 'HELP RQD' once again.

Here is my current script, but it only sends continuous emails if just Cell C7 contains 'HELP RQD', until the C7's value is changed to something else:

```
function HelpRqd(e) {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("C7").getValue();
  if (valueToCheck == "HELP RQD") {
    MailApp.sendEmail("example@example.com", "Help Rqd", "Help requested for STATION 2 at 12:00");
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to expand on this to include searching within a range and emailing the corresponding header information?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can you explain about your current script? Because from your script and question, it seems that you want to send an email only when the dropdown list of the cell `C7` is changed to the value of `HELP RQD`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I clarified my post, please feel free to take another look - my current script only works for one specified cell, in this case C7, but I am trying to set it up so that if any cell in range B2:D7 changes, an email will be sent with the appropriate heading data for both the cell's column and row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can continue to use the `getRange()` method but expand it to the full range and check each with a loop.*

#### Code:

The following code gets the  Station number from row 1 and the time from column A based on the cell designated "HELP RQD" and dynamically inserts it into the email:

```js
function HelpRqd(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var fullRange = sheet.getRange("B2:D7").getValues();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < fullRange.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < fullRange[i].length; j++) {

      if (j == 0) {
        var cell = "B" + (i + 1);
      }
      else if (j == 1) {
        var cell = "C" + (i + 1);
      }
      else if (j == 2) {
        var cell = "D" + (i + 1);
      }  

      if (fullRange[i][j] == "HELP RQD") {      
        if (scriptProperties.getProperty(cell) == "HELP RQD") {
          continue;
        }
        else if (scriptProperties.getProperty(cell) != "HELP RQD") {
          scriptProperties.setProperty(cell, "HELP RQD");
          
          var time = sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 2)).getDisplayValue();
          if (j == 0) {
            var station = sheet.getRange("B" + 1).getValue();
          }
          else if (j == 1) {
            var station = sheet.getRange("C" + 1).getValue();
          }
          else if (j == 2) {
            var station = sheet.getRange("D" + 1).getValue();
          } 

          MailApp.sendEmail("example@domain.com", "Help Rqd", "Help requested for " + station + " at " + time);
        }
      }
      else {
        if (scriptProperties.getProperty(cell) == "HELP RQD") {
          scriptProperties.setProperty(cell, "CLEAR");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Method `getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)